# How to change the Custom Timer Job's title after initial deployment

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server, custom-timer-job, timer-jobs

I created a SharePoint Custom Timer Job in Visual Studio 2012 following the steps given in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S) by Ravi Rachchh. It works fine.

However, I wanted to change the `Title` of the Timer Job. So I changed the below given line in the constructor.

```
this.Title = "MNM's Test Timer Job";
```

However after re-deploying and activating the Feature. The Central Admin Job Definitions page shows the old `Title`.

What Am I missing here?

Comment: did you retract it completey and then redeploy it? also did you recycle the timer services on server?

Comment: Yes. We did retract and after re-deploying we also performed the 'net stop  sptimerv4' & 'net start sptimerv4'.

Comment: did you change in all constructors? step 4 of this blog http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S

Comment: Yes we did! Did a search on the entire VS project for the old title. does not exist.

Comment: how many server in the farm? i would say completely remove it from server, recycle timer services(on all server) and then re-add and redeploy the new solution.

Comment: only one server. Ok I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell for changing Title

```
$t = get-sptimerjob | where { $_.Title -eq "MNM's Test Timer Job" }
$t.Title = "New MNM's Test Timer Job"
$t.Update()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Jazakallahu Khairan :)! Any idea why the code doesn't update the title?

Comment: I have observed this behavior, mainly with farm having multiple servers. Not sure exact cause.

Comment: we have only one server in the farm.

Comment: Ok in that case try restarting OWSTimer service

Comment: I did try the 'net stop sptimerv4' & 'net start sptimerv4' commands. Still no luck!